# Fastest way to map elements into percentile? Using pandas now but wondering if there is a faster way

Tags: python, pandas, performance, numpy

Here is my code where I convert from numpy to pandas first then rank, and then i go back to numpy... its the slowest part of my code so I wanted to see if anyone knew of a better way:

```
preds = np.dot(xtest , weights)
preds = pd.DataFrame(preds)
preds = preds.rank(axis = 0, pct=True)
preds = np.where(preds > 0.75, 1,0)
```

Comment: There's a simple quantile function which allows you to do this very easily, but it'll result in you having to create a boolean mask to filter out the ones in a specific quantile (e.g. for `[1, 20, 30, 40, 50]`, quantile will return `[1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th]`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As hinted in comments `quantile` could be used. The solution becomes a one-liner to directly get the final array from original `preds` array -

```
preds_final_out = (preds>np.quantile(preds, 0.75, axis=0)).view('i1')
```

So, this one-step would replace the last three steps, namely :

```
preds = pd.DataFrame(preds)
preds = preds.rank(axis = 0, pct=True)
preds = np.where(preds > 0.75, 1,0)
```

Timings comparison on a 1M dataset -

```
In [51]: preds = np.random.randint(0,10000,1000000)

# Original soln
In [53]: %%timeit
    ...: preds1 = pd.DataFrame(preds)
    ...: preds2 = preds1.rank(axis = 0, pct=True)
    ...: preds3 = np.where(preds2 > 0.75, 1,0)
119 ms ± 263 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

# With proposed soln
In [54]: %timeit (preds>np.quantile(preds, 0.75, axis=0)).view('i1')
11 ms ± 180 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: so even faster than I imagined it could be... thanks

Comment: what does the .view('i1') do at the end? This code doesn't output the same preds as mine.

Comment: @xxanissrxx That's just an efficient way to convert boolean to int.

Comment: the preds that your code outputs isn't the same... I can't fix it because I don't understand how it works..

Comment: @xxanissrxx Can you upload the dataset somewhere and we can compare then?

Comment: its 9GB... I think what you're missing is that the preds.rank(axis=0, pct = True) was ranking elements against other elements of the same column, not elements of the entire matrix. That being said, I still don't know how to fix your one-liner.

Comment: I think I got it, just added axis =0: ```(preds>np.quantile(preds, 0.75,axis=0)).view('i1')```

Comment: @xxanissrxx Ah yeah! That's it. Edited.